# WPF How to give multiple resource dictionaries the same class?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, resourcedictionary

I'm not sure if I'm asking the right type of question, but here's my issue.

I have multiple resource dictionaries, and I would like to allow for users to customise these resource dictionaries to create their own styles. There are [styles built in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PURMx.png), and styles loaded from files, each style has a single resource dictionary with [a specified class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYxCg.png).

I wanted to keep the styles separate so they could be customised, but I need some event handlers, so I made a generic event handler class **ResourceDictionaryEventHandler.cs**.

The issue now is when I assign more than one resource dictionary the same class, I get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWN80.png). The [app.xaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXxQ0.png) had some of the styles already loaded, but even after only loading one set of styles I still got the same error.

Its weird too because it seemed to be working earlier, but simply restarting Visual Studio the issue surfaced.

[This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PURMx.png) does have 2 resource dictionaries per style, but only one have them has been assigned a class.

So how do I assign this EventHandler class to multiple resource dictionaries? Or is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

I made a small example for you. I have added two resource dictionaries named Dark.xaml and Light.xaml to the project.

[image]

I have defined the colors that I will use in these resource dictionaries.

Dark.xaml Code

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ThemeExample">
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ColorMode" Color="DarkBlue"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Light.xaml code

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ThemeExample">

<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ColorMode" Color="LightBlue"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Then I added two buttons to the home page and changed the source dictionaries to change the color of the frame.

MainWindow.xaml Code

```
<Button x:Name="DarkButton" Content="Dark" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="151,132,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="DarkButton_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="LightButton" Content="Light" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="248,132,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="LightButton_Click"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="{DynamicResource ColorMode}" Width="100" Height="100"></Rectangle>
```

LightButton_Click Code

```
 private void LightButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var resources = Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries;

        var existingResourceDictionary = Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries
                                        .Where(rd => rd.Source != null)
                                        .SingleOrDefault(rd => Regex.Match(rd.Source.OriginalString, @"(\/((Light)|(Dark)))").Success);

        var source = $"pack://application:,,,/Light.xaml";
        var newResourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri(source) };

        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Remove(existingResourceDictionary);
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(newResourceDictionary);
    }
```

DarkButton_Click

```
private void DarkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var resources = Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries;

        var existingResourceDictionary = Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries
                                        .Where(rd => rd.Source != null)
                                        .SingleOrDefault(rd => Regex.Match(rd.Source.OriginalString, @"(\/((Light)|(Dark)))").Success);

        var source = $"pack://application:,,,/Dark.xaml";
        var newResourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri(source) };

        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Remove(existingResourceDictionary);
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(newResourceDictionary);
    }
```

Don't forget to include the same color key in app.xaml.

```
<Application x:Class="ThemeExample.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ThemeExample"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ColorMode" Color="DarkBlue"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: This is wonderful, but I have a style, which has a text field in it, in which i need to get the text field changed event. and it being a resource, it needs a class to direct the event to

Comment: its a style for a grid, and that grid has such text field

Comment: I could not establish the link between the color theme and the text field. Are you sure that what you are doing is the right way? Also, I don't understand exactly what you want to do. Sorry, my English is not very good.

Comment: I have a 1 Grid, that grid contains a style, and in that style, in the contentPresenter, there is a textblock, i need to manage the events for that textblock, in order to do that, i need to give it a class, as the xaml files are Resource Dictionaries, and those resource dictionaries, control the location, style, color, etc for the buttons